# If I change the parametrization of a line integral would the power in the work change?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, physics

Working with line integrals I noticed when the parametrization is changed the answers are the same amount of work.  But isn't t the time element as well so if I follow the same path using a different parametrization  would not the power of the work change ?

Certainly the vector field stays the same and the path remains constant through the field so if you change t then would not the unit of time change necessarily ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The power is the work made for unit of time thus there is not contradiction for the fact that work doesn't change with different parametrization.

Indeed we have for a given parametrization $\vec r(t)$

$$W=\int_{t_0}^{t_1}\vec F(t)\cdot \vec r'(t)dt$$

but $t$ here is a parameter which is not related to the time.

Comment: Is it the case then when you change parametrization the unit of time stays the same even though the function for the path changes ? As for example  if  the path is over y = x^2 and the new parametrization is x =  sin(t)  , y = sin^2(t) .  you are saying the time is constant for any motion through the path? that would mean the distance is the same..how can that be?

Comment: The parametrization is used to represent the given trajectory as a curve in the space and the parameter "t" in general doesn't identify a time. Indeed the evaluation of the work is time independent. We can do the same work to lift 1 kg for a meter in a second or in an hour but the work is the same.

Comment: gimusi ...yes thank you ...i understand work is time independent but will the power be different ...that is what is confusing me...that is why I bring up "time"...maybe my confusion is this...the difference between path and parametrization ....thank you ...maybe if you can find and easy example.....

Answer (score 1):

Both the work and the power are defined with geometric vectors, so they can't depend on the parametrization.

Comment: please look at my comment just above your explanation ...thank you